# Uso o skype significa que tenho uma porta aberta?

Tags: skype

Boas,

Por eu usar skype no meu computador significa que tenho uma porta da minha internet aberta?

Se a resposta for nao"

E estando em chamada ? Fico com alguma porta do router aberta?

Se sim:

DA para fechar nao desintalando o skype ?

Obrigado

Comment: Apesar de eu achar a pergunta boa, ela está fora do escopo.

Comment: O que e escopo ?

Comment: Ainda sou muito novato nisto xD

Comment: Diogo, bem vindo ao SOpt! Esse site é sobre programação. Sua pergunta deveria ter sido feita no superuser.com . Aproveitando a situação, existe já uma proposta para criação de um _superuser_ em Português! Caso se interesse, acesse http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues e clique em COMMIT, no topo da tela!

Comment: Ja fiz, peco desculpa se tambem nao devia perguntar isto, mas qual a difrenca entre os dois ? Este e de perguntas sobre um assunto e o superuser sobre outro ?

Comment: Para saber mais sobre o SOpt, sugiro que leia: [tour] e aqui você verá os temas aceitos pelo SOpt -> http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/

Comment: Ok, vou faze-lo, obrigado :p